# Store variable in Chrome Extension (domain 1), but I need it in remote domain (domain 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a Chrome Extension.
In the box extension I allow users to store a variable (like a URL).
Then, in the page when the script is active, I have to retreive this value.

Example

*Chrome Extension:*

localStorage.setItem("url", $("#url").val());

*Domain.net* (like facebook.com)

var my_url = localStorage.getItem("url");

BUT localStorage doesn't allow cross domain. Don't reply me saying to use GlobalStorage, is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [`storage API`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) and combine it with [`message passing`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html). You didn't mention where it is you are saving the value so I am going to assume it is in a popup or something like that. For example:

**Popup.js**

```
//Let's define urlData to be the url you obtained from the user
chrome.storage.local.set({'urlData':urlData});
```

You then said that you needed it in the page so if you inject a content script into that page you can get the value like this:

**Content Script**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method:'getUrl'},function(urlData){
  //do whatever you want with the urlData in here. I will just log it
  console.log(urlData);
});
```

**Background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
  if(message.method == "getUrl"){
    chrome.storage.local.get('urlData',function(items){
      sendResponse(items.urlData);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to save the data to localStorage in the domain where it will be fetched.
it sounds like you control that domain, so you can create a proxy using a simple HTML file on that domain, call it saver.html:

```
<html><script>
   localStrorage.url=decodeURIComponent(location.hash.slice(1));
</script></html>
```

to save from the other site/extension, you create a new iframe that points to that html file, concatenating the data as the hash segment of the url:

```
var theValue="this will be saved as 'url' in localStorage ",
 fr=document.createElement("iframe");
 fr.style.display='none';
 fr.src="http://mysite.com/saver.html#"+encodeURIComponent(theValue);
 document.body.appendChild(fr);
```

in this fashion, the data is passed to the correct domain and saved to localStorage.

if needed, you can use top.sendMessage() in the proxy html page to signal to your app that the data has been written to the remote localStorage.

Comment: Mmmh the site is facebook.com, you have reasoned like if the domain is mine?

Comment: well if you can't host the html file on the site, you can't do it at all, but then why is there a need to set the value on a site you can't control enough to read the value even if it were saved?

Comment: I'm making an extension that allows you to export images and text from Facebook to external website that have the php script installed. You decide on which server load your stuff. Any solution? :)